# How to change encoding in .net maui?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, maui, .net-maui.shell

I'm trying to write an app by using .net maui.
When I use Ukrainian letters I get an error.
As far as I understand, this problem can be solved by changing encoding, but I don't know how to do this correctly.

I'm trying to change encoding to windows1251 in appshell, but it wasn't successful. Maybe I forgot something.

Comment: "get an error" - what **specific** error are you getting?

Comment: xmlns task failed unexpectedly

Comment: Anyway, I found. The problem was in page. It doesn't contain <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> . Now it's work normal, even with utf-8 encording